# Spivak's Calculus Assumptions 2

Tags: proof-writing, proof-explanation, axioms, foundations

Spivak's Calculus is known for being the best Calculus book when it comes to rigour, but I think I've found an assumption he makes during his very first proof!

The axioms are:

P1 (Associativity of Addition): (a + b) + c = a + (b + c)

P2 (Additive Identity): a + 0 = a

P3 (Additive Inverse): a + (-a) = 0

P4 (Commutativity): a + b = b + a

The Proof:

(1) If a + x = a,

(2) Then (-a) + (a + x) = (-a) + a *(adding (-a) to both sides)

(3) Then ((-a) + a) + x = 0 *(using P1 and P3)

(4) Then 0 + x = 0 *(using P3)

(5) Then x = 0 *(using P4 and P2)

Conclusion: If a + x = a, Then x = 0

My problem is in the very first step from (1) to (2). Where is the justification for adding (-a) to both sides? Seems to me if we are going to do such formal proofs with such basic axioms for such simple theorems, such an assumption is quite severe? May as well assume the conclusion! To clarify, mathematically the assumption is:

If a = b, Then a + c = b + c

You can only add numbers to both sides of the equation if you establish this truth (either as a theorem or an axiom). I don't think it's possible to prove it with P1-P4.

So should it be included as one of Spivak's axioms?

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are right, Spivak hasn't defined what the symbol $=$ means and well a plethora of other problems if you want to be absolutely formal. But I believe you can make the exact same objection about any step of the proof. What does it mean mathematically for something to follow? Why if (2) then (3)? The thing is, Spivack is using another structure implicitly which is first order logic, that provides a way to structure mathematical thought unambiguously. In https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First-order_logic#Equality_and_its_axioms you can see that you can define the symbol, but well in the same page you can see it still not as simple as just making a list of more and more axioms. You can see that it follows from substitution for formulas. I would still consider Spivack rigorous in the same way Euclid's Element is rigorous, the things that are implicitly assumed are for the purposes of the book "universal", even though by modern standards of formality they clearly aren't. Though you would need to read on logic and set theory to have the modern perspective and it is no simple task.

Comment: Will do when I get there thanks. I guess what seems weird to me is not that Spivak is not 100% rigorous, but that the theorems he is proving and axioms he is using are on the same logical level of an axiom such as: if a = b then a + c = b + c. It's like if he had omitted P2 and just assumed 0 + a = a. I wonder if there's a theory for "to what degree" a proof is rigorous?

Comment: In general a mathematical argument is rigorous if it is formed is such a way that cannot be refuted. But well, for an expert in a field an argument can be perfectly clear even if it isn't for a beginner. But also, obvious concepts can be challenged in more abstract or fundamental fields. Spivak is just being a bit naive because most people have a pretty clear notion of equality in math. But as you go further into the book you will se you will not be able to list extra axioms without that list being infinite as replacing things that are equal into other formulas or functions is fundamental

Answer (score 4):

The wording is "adding $-a$ to both sides", but that is not what actually happens. You just use $a+x=a$. Then
$$
(-a)+(a+x)=(-a)+a
$$
simply because we are replacing $a+x$ with $a$. The "truth" that Spivak is using is that if two things are equal, you can replace one for the other, which is the whole point of equality.

Comment: I challenge your last sentence. In order to be able to swap equal numbers inside an equation you would need an even stronger axiom: If a = b, then f(a) = f(b). If 2 things are equal, that does not mean you can replace them inside an equation. The relevant axiom for equality is: If a = b and b = c then a = c, but that does not imply if a = b, then f(a) = f(b), or any special cases of that like when f(x) = x + c -> if a = b then a + c = b + c.

Comment: "If two things are equal, that does not mean you can replace them inside an equation". Of course it does. What does "equal" mean to you?

Comment: Way to take my comment out of context. The reason you can swap equal numbers in an equation (or function), is ONLY because of the axiom: if a = b then f(a) = f(b), or some variant. Perfect counter example to your position is the axiom: if a = b and b = c then a = c. If you can swap numbers just because they are equal then you wouldn't need this axiom. As for what equal means, a definition is not necessary. Real applied maths can interpret equals to mean whatever they want, but for pure math we only care about it's properties. That's the whole point of axioms.

Comment: No. It's because "equal" actually means "equal". You can make your own theory, if you want, where "equal" means something else, but you'd be talking a different language than the one spoken by mathematicians.

Comment: Lol so the definition of "equal" is... equal! Wow brilliant definition so rigorous! I like how you just ignored my counter example too...

Answer (score 1):

Let me suggest following explanation variant: just before these axioms Spivak defined operation addition "for numbers-the sum  $a  +  b$  exists  for  any  two  given  numbers  $a$  and  $b$"(p.3). Operation here means function $X \times X \to X$, so if we take one number, $a+x$ for example, that addition to it other number, for example $-a$, will give same result. So if $a + x = a$, then $(-a) + (a + x) = (-a) + a$ from addition unambiguity.

Comment: You proved both (-a) + (a + x) and (-a) + a exist, you didn't prove they are equal?

Comment: @SenZen. Let's denote addition operation by $A:X \times X \to X$. Then $A(x,y)$ have unique value for same pairs, as $A$ is function. Now we have from one side $A(-a, a+x)$ and from another side $A(-a, a)$. By assumption second member of pairs equal, so pairs equal, what will be for corresponding values?

Comment: Why are the pairs equal? You've assumed if a = b, then (c, a) = (c, b). That's the exact assumption I'm taking about, just in this new function form.

Comment: When pairs equal? $(x,y)=(a,b) \Leftrightarrow x=a \land y=b$ it is not new assumption (your assumption wrote in question, about numbers) but pairs equality definition. How you define $X \times X$ without this to have addition operation?

Comment: Spivak never uses Set-theoretic definitions. I think this is the issue at hand

Comment: @Fedro. How we can understand addition operation - what is it? And by the way, explain, please, what you mean under "issue at hand".

Comment: The problem is not the usual definition of addition as an operation, but how it is defined in Spivak's book. Spivak never mentions the set theoretic definition in the first chapter and just states the axioms in the OP. He basically leaves the real numbers as defined through the axioms.

Comment: @Fedro. Spivak have addition operation before axioms on p.3. So it is necessary to understand it in some way to read book. How?

Comment: Spivak does not define addition, he just states the minimum properties it should have in the form of axioms and goes from there. It isn't necessary to define something in order to do math with it, so long as you list the required axioms. Perfect example is with ZFC = No definition of a set. Let me ask you Zkutch, you state set theory axioms using sets, so is it necessary to understand sets in some way to use them? ZFC doesn't think so.

Comment: @SenZen. We can speak about my position against set theory, its axioms, definition of set and more, about meta-mathematics etc. If so, then lets open new question or go to some chat. Do you you want it? But here we discuss Spivak, he introduce addition in same page, above axioms, and nothing can help simple question: what is addition "$+$" in Spivak? I suggested view based on concept of function (Spivak p.47) and ordered pair (Spivak p.54, appendix. ordered pairs) and it answers question.

Comment: Then how do you define the concept of a function?

Comment: @zkutch Spivak is sloppy as he introduces addition and the real numbers and functions later. His definition of a function is also mostly intuitive and he only covers ordered pairs in an Apendix. My answer is more to the question "Is Spivak rigorous" which I think no in the strict sense, but for the general purposes of the text I would say the problems are all technicalities really that don't undermine the core of his arguments. The book is meant for people of different areas who are not required to learn set theoretic definitions.

Comment: @SenZen. Not me. Spivak defined it. On page 39 there is so called "provisional" definition. Then on 9 pages he explains his view and write exact definition on page 47. Then feeling some insufficiency he added appendix from page 54. There are very interesting last 4 lines from this appendix, where despite on just brought he again speaks about "rule". Finishing, I think, this definition is enough in case of your question. Personally my view is little different.

Comment: @Fedro. Firstly, Michael David Spivak is alive respectful mathematician and I feel word "sloppy" not very nice with respect to him. Second,  you wrote "My answer is more to the question "Is Spivak rigorous" " - I agree, but, have doubt, that you and me, if we mean same under word "rigorous". But it's not OP question. We discuss ways from (1) to (2) and necessity of new axiom.

Comment: @zkutch I used sloppy to describe his construction from a strict and orthodox mathematical perspective, not really as an overall criticism of him or his work. His definitions of ordered pair uses the already defined real numbers which would make it circular to then define addition like that. In an axiomatic system this is not allowed. However, I'm not saying the book is bad or anything, and yes I believe it is rigorous in my own personal understanding of the word. Just that if you want a book that starts from any sort of math foundation then I don't think Spivak does that.

Comment: Whether Spivak is being rigorous or not isn't really the issue. Of course an introduction to calculus isn't going to be 100% rigorous. What I find strange is that given the medium level of rigor Spivak HAS taken on, he doesn't include the closure of addition axiom (see above) which is on the same level of medium rigor as the other axioms he's adopted, since without it his whole theory falls apart.

Comment: Hey how do you guys reply in comments?